# How to get the Current Value using SELECT query

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have this:

```
echo '<form>
    <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">Select a person:</option>';
$result = $conn->query("SELECT firstName,agendaID FROM agendas WHERE ownerID='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row['agendaID'] . '">' . $row['firstName'] . '</option>';
}
$result->close();

echo '
    </select>
    </form>';
```

the `showUser()` script will print values in a table based on what is selected from the menu. The problem is that upon refreshing the page, the select option is lost and it goes back to default, so the table is not displayed anymore. Having an id that I got through `GET`(the id of the current selected option), how can I set the select to keep the display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell the browser which row of the select dropdown is the currently selected item by using

```
<option selected="selected" .....>
```

So now you just need to know what the user selected, this will be sent to the form when you click the submit in either the $_GET or $_POST arrays. As you have not specified a `method` on your `<form>` it will be the $_GET array.

So you need to test which was selected and alter this code something like this:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $sel = (isset($_GET['users']) && $_GET_['users'] == $row['agendaID'] ) 
           ? 'selected="selected"' 
           : '';

    echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $row['agendaID'] . '">' . $row['firstName'] . '</option>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's right. When you don't specify a value and you refresh the page the selected value goes to the default (the first) value. You can save the selected choice with localStorage. Add in your showUser function:

```
localStorage.setItem('usersValue', THE_JAVASCRIPT_VARIABLE);
```

That will store the selected value in localStorage. To reset the selected value you can use JQuery:

```
var selectedValue =  localStorage.getItem('usersValue');
if(selectedValue !== null)
{
    $('select[name="users"]').val(selectedValue);
    showUser(selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: Where did it look like they were using javascript. They are having enough trouble with basic PHP without adding to their confusion.

Comment: **onchange="showUser(this.value)** calls a javascript function, right?

Answer (score 0):

Just check if `agentID` is same as one from `_GET`:

```
echo '<form>
         <select name="users" id="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">';
echo '<option value="">Select a person:</option>';
$sessionId = (int) $_SESSION['id'];
$result = $conn->query("SELECT `firstName`, `agendaID` FROM `agendas` WHERE `ownerID` = '{$sessionId}'");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $extra = '';        

    if (!empty($_GET['ID']) && (int) $row['agendaID'] == (int) $_GET['ID']) {
        $extra = 'selected';
    }

    echo "<option value='{$row['agendaID']} {$extra}>{$row['firstName']}</option>";
}

$result->close();

echo '</select>
    </form>';
```

And on `$(document).ready()` trigger `showUser($("#users option:selected").val())` with selected value

Answer (score 0):

Add selected attribute to the option based on your get value and run your showUsers(selected value) function on page load. Get the selected value using js.